# How to get open sockets from core dump?

Tags: linux, coredump

I have a core dump of a dead process. I want to see the sockets opened in that proclet when it was running.

Is it possible to see the output of netstats for the dead process in a core dump?

How to get kernel pointer from a core file? Is a core dump also the dump of the kernel, or only a dump of the user memory?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

you cannot see the output of netstat from core dump.
Core dump is for the process itself, comprising the application code and library calls, not of the kernel unless your core is a kernel crash dump.

**Long answer**

Core dumps allow you to see:

- Timestamp of the failure
- Active threads at the time of the failure
- Steps leading up to the failure (stack frame)

To be able to do application specific failure analysis, like sockets in your case you would have to rely on the log files or write specific logs as part of your application.

If you can run the process again using

```
$ strace -f -o output.txt <process-name>
```

That would allow you to trace the system calls and locate the socket system calls that succeeded and ones that failed. The trace is saved to file output.txt which you can search for system calls.